Does noun function as adverb with に attached
I am reading a Japanese book that has this sentence:

マリヤの円光を現実に見た夜もあったのです。

The 現実に here sounds like an adverb to me.

現実 is a noun. 現実に adverbially modifies 見た. I'm afraid it's not completely clear to me what you want to know though.

@user3856370 I have edited my question. It sounds like an adverb to not a noun in this case.

You're right that に can make a noun(名詞) or a な-adj(形容動詞) into an adverb.

静かな夜　→ 静かに眠る
緑の葉　→ 緑に光る

However, I'd argue that in your case, the に actually denotes location, since 現実 (reality) can be interpreted as a "place", as opposed to fantasy or something. Just like in English we say "in reality", or "in my room", Japanese is also 現実(の中)に or 僕の部屋(の中)に.
Even though, phrases indicating locations in both English and Japanese are still considered adverbial phrases, since they modify and add information to the verb.
